# How to use CSS styles with Google Apps table (grid)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm a beginner looking for some help styling a table produced by a Google Apps script, it's a table which displays a list of Google Contacts, and started with the code from [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/contacts-services/display-contacts-in-a-table).

I've been trying to style it by adding `.setStyleAttributes({})` to `app.createGrid`, `grid.setWidget` and `app.createLabel` but I can't seem to find a way to target the `<td>` elements on all browsers.  The current page looks OK in Chrome but I can't even get border collapse in Firefox...

What I would like is to be able to:

- Have borders collapsing on Firefox (done now thanks)
- Style the cell borders to get horizontal blue lines and no verticals (or white verticals)

Anyway, here is the code for producing the table, any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

```
//Create grid to hold the contacts data, styles set <table> inline styles
var grid = app.createGrid(sorted_contacts.length+1,6)
  .setBorderWidth(1)
  .setCellPadding(5)
  .setStyleAttributes({borderCollapse: "collapse", border: "1px solid #D1E2FF", borderBottom: "1px solid #D1E2FF", borderTop: "1px solid #D1E2FF", borderLeft: "1px solid #fff", borderRight: "1px solid #fff"});

//Create the header row
grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Name').setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#384C80"}))
    .setWidget(0, 1, app.createLabel('Email').setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#384C80"}))
    .setWidget(0, 2, app.createLabel('Home').setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#384C80"}))
    .setWidget(0, 3, app.createLabel('Work').setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#384C80"}))
    .setWidget(0, 4, app.createLabel('Mobile').setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#384C80"}))
    .setWidget(0, 5, app.createLabel('Address').setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#384C80"}))

//Write all the contacts in grid/table
for (var i=0; i<sorted_contacts.length; i++){

  //Display the first name + surname or just the surname
  if(sorted_contacts[i][0]!='') grid.setWidget(i+1, 0, app.createLabel(sorted_contacts[i][0]+' '+sorted_contacts[i][1]).setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", color: "#2E2E2E"}));
  else
    grid.setWidget(i+1, 0, app.createLabel(sorted_contacts[i][1]).setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", color: "#2E2E2E"}));

  //Display the rest of the fields
  grid.setWidget(i+1, 1, app.createLabel(sorted_contacts[i][2]).setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", color: "#2E2E2E"}));
  grid.setWidget(i+1, 2, app.createLabel(sorted_contacts[i][3]).setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", color: "#2E2E2E"}));
  grid.setWidget(i+1, 3, app.createLabel(sorted_contacts[i][4]).setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", color: "#2E2E2E"}));
  grid.setWidget(i+1, 4, app.createLabel(sorted_contacts[i][5]).setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", color: "#2E2E2E"}));
  grid.setWidget(i+1, 5, app.createLabel(sorted_contacts[i][6]).setStyleAttributes({fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", color: "#2E2E2E"}));
}

//add the grid/table to the panel
panel.add(grid);

//add the panel to the application
app.add(panel);
return app;
```

Comment: Try .setCellSpacing(0) on the Grid.

Comment: Also, for readability and ease of modifying, replace `{fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#384C80"}` with `styleGridHeader` and then define above it `var styleGridHeader = {fontFamily: "Verdana, sans-serif", fontWeight: "bold", color: "#384C80"}`.

Comment: Thanks Phil, both those suggestions were very helpful.  I've tidied up the code by using variables for the styles, and adding the setCellSpacing has got the borders collapsing on Firefox.  All that's left is the cell border colours on FF and IE.  On Chrome the verticals are white, so it looks like horizontal blue lines, but on FF & IE I can only colour the very outside lines, the interior are all black.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Here you go:https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyyQ5Q1iQ4Rtq3kt9Yspz1l6o6s6YCy-GqqAlG9mv4Sm0NtoEda/exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want `grid.setRowStyleAttributes(rowNum, styles)`, or `grid.setColumnStyleAttributes(colNum, styles)` or the special grid version of setStyleAttributes that targets an individual `<td>` - `grid.setStyleAttributes(rowNum, colNum, styles)`

Comment: I gave `setColumnStyleAttributes` a try as follows:  `//Set column styles`
   `var myColumnStyles = {border: "1px solid #D1E2FF", borderBottom: "1px solid #D1E2FF", borderTop: "1px solid #D1E2FF", borderLeft: "1px solid #fff", borderRight: "1px solid #fff"};`
  
    `for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
     grid.setColumnStyleAttributes(i, myColumnStyles)
    }`

It looks like it adds inline styles to the col elements, and in fact the vertical lines have gone white in all browsers now (see the link).  So just the horizontal lines now

Comment: And the grid.setStyleAttributes targets the individual <td> just like you said.  Thanks very much for your help!